# trying to concatenate the string but got error

Tags: mysql, sql

HI  I am trying to concatenate the string but i got error  at this line

```
sql += " "+"WHERE memberToMship_PayMethod="' +Cash"'";
```

like too many characters in character literal....

can any one help on this pls ......

```
                              sql = @"SELECT members.member_Id, members.member_Lastname, members.member_Firstname, members.member_IsBiometric";
  sql += ","+"members.member_Reference, members.member_Dob, members.member_PostCode, mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name, mshiptypes.mshipType_Name";
  sql += ","+"membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate";
  sql += " "+"FROM members LEFT JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id";
  sql += " "+"WHERE memberToMship_PayMethod="' +Cash"'";
```

Comment: Why the hell are you concatenating `" "` with `"FROM MEMBERS ..."` instead of just doing `" FROM MEMBERS ..."`

Comment: cash is the one of the column  value

Comment: would you reformat if possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql += " "+"WHERE memberToMship_PayMethod="' +Cash"'";
```

should probably be

```
sql += " "+"WHERE memberToMship_PayMethod='" +Cash+ "'";
```

or

```
sql += " "+"WHERE memberToMship_PayMethod='Cash'";
```

Comment: Wow, you're really kinda blindly hacking things together, are you? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a quote *outside* the double quotes, and you were missing a `+`. Try this:

```
sql += " "+"WHERE memberToMship_PayMethod='" + Cash + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
     sql = @"SELECT members.member_Id, members.member_Lastname, members.member_Firstname, members.member_IsBiometric";
  sql += ","+"members.member_Reference, members.member_Dob, members.member_PostCode, mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name, mshiptypes.mshipType_Name";
  sql += ","+"membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate";
  sql += " "+"FROM members LEFT JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id";
  sql += " "+"LEFT JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id";
  sql += " "+"WHERE memberToMship_PayMethod='" + "Cash" + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you don't need to concate, you query is simple so you could use:

```
sqlQuery = @"Select * from ...........
..........................
where CashMethod="+Cash;
```